# VS Code + MS C++ extension on linux - stuck on setup tutorial

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I am new to VS Code (used VS Community eventually) and tried to set up VS Code on raspberry pi (pi-os) and PC (Debian) following *Get Started with C++ on Linux in Visual Studio Code* but got stuck on the part setting up the launch.json for debugging the helloworld.cpp - as there is no such selection (with similar or comparable naming) as shown in the tutorial. If I copy the example given in the tutorial I can start debugging but don't get any output in terminal or the debug-console (other than debugger info), neither in the loop nor from the last cout statement.

just feeling a little frustrated for being so ... newb ...

[selection in tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjOJo.png)
[selection in my setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmp9o.png)

Comment: Could you cite, what exactly doesn't match with the tutorial? How does your `launch.json` look like? How does your debugging look like from VS Code (in words, or screenshots)?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the "Terminal" tab when running?

Comment: A very unfortunate effect of the modern "release updates as frequently as possible" approach to software development is that tutorials and other learning materials usually lag behind the current release.

Comment: added screenshots to my question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got it working.

It is best to choose `C/C++: (gdb) Launch` for configuration and adapt the settings for `program` and `cwd` according to the tutorial.

The section with `prelaunch Task` is not really necessary if one builds prior to debugging.

If for any reason it is wanted, make sure to use the same name as in the `tasks.json` under `label`.

If I insert a second

```
cout << endl
```

at the end, I see the output before the program terminates; that let me draw the conclusion that `cout` output appears in `whole lines` only.

none the less the tutorial should be updated...